# Learning Locker: php artisan migrate trouble

Tags: php, ubuntu, lrs, learning-locker

I've been following the below link for quite some days now and I'm having trouble executing each steps but successfully found a solution for each and every one of them but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution when I executed the command "php artisan migrate" as you can see from the link below;
http://www.jpablo128.com/how-to-install-learning-locker/#comment-1498

It gave me an error message;
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Patchwork\Utf8\Bootup' not found in /var/www/learninglocker/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 46

I tried countless solutions but I failed on fixing it.

Comment: Have you ran `sudo composer install` like the guide says?

Comment: Yeah but it gave me an error;
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: But on the guide it says "At the end I get an error with no output. I don’t know why it happens, but I ignored it." 
So I didn't really get to that topic

Comment: If composer hasn't installed all the packages in the `vendor` folder you won't be able to fix the 'class not found' error.

Comment: I have a lot of problems here when I tried to install composer. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Problem 1
    - Installation request for barracuda/copy 1.1.7 -> satisfiable by barracuda/copy[1.1.7].
    - barracuda/copy 1.1.7 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

Comment: Problem 2
    - Installation request for dropbox/dropbox-sdk v1.1.6 -> satisfiable by dropbox/dropbox-sdk[v1.1.6].
    - dropbox/dropbox-sdk v1.1.6 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

Comment: Problem 3
    - Installation request for guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 -> satisfiable by guzzle/guzzle[v3.9.3].
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

Comment: Problem 4
    - barracuda/copy 1.1.7 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - league/flysystem-copy 1.0.3 requires barracuda/copy ~1.1 -> satisfiable by barracuda/copy[1.1.7].
    - Installation request for league/flysystem-copy 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-copy[1.0.3].

Comment: and then it says this;   To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mongo.ini
    - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini

Comment: You need PHP curl extension. Check the comments here http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php and search the web on how to install it and enable it depending on your OS.